# Sending message through Handler to an Activity not yet created

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, handler, message

I'm developing an Android application. This app consists of two activity.

- Main activity
- Secondary activity (called from Main Activity)

I have a thread that using the `handler` mechanism passes a messagge to Main Activity, and this activity showes an image.

I wish this icon was shown in both Activity. But if I'm sure that the Main activity is yet created, I can't say the same for Secondary Activity. So, what happens if I try to send message from thread to an Activity that isn't yet created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wish this icon was shown in both Activity. But if I'm sure that the Main activity is yet created, I can't say the same for Secondary Activity.

Only one Activity can be active at a time, so you need to save the common data in some type of [data storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) (like a [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)), or you can use global variables, or you can pass this information back and forth in Intents.

Whichever method you choose, it needs to be available whenever the next Activity starts. I suggest SharedPreferences since they are relatively simple and are not deleted when the app closes.

Comment: I know, @Sam. But I want that if I'm in the main activity and the message arrive the icon is shown, and if I'm in the secondary activity and the message arrive the icon is shown too.

Comment: You can create a custom listener. It will "broadcast" the event when you select a new icon to any Activity that is active and has your listener. [This example](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) from the Developer's Guide uses Fragments, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thank you, @Sam. Can you give me more detalis about this solution?

Comment: Sure, but it's hard to provide specifics without seeing your code. However do you understand the code in the link? The basic approach is create the listener's interface, create listener objects, pass the references of these listener objects to the event, and finally execute each listener's callback when the event occurs.

Comment: I find this in your link "When the activity receives a callback through the interface, it can share the information with other fragments in the layout as necessary." So, I can't understand how use this mechanism for share the information with other activity.

Comment: That is just a fancy way of saying your callback can pass whatever data you want. For instance you could use `onIconChanged(int resId);` and this callback would send the new resource id (`R.drawable.xxx`) to every Activity with the callback. Or you can pass a URL link to the icon or even the icon itself.